# Skin Effect and Eddy Currents Question

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

Wikipedia has the following image explaining the skin effect:
[image]

With the caption:
Cause of skin effect. A current $I$ flowing through a conductor induces a magnetic field $H$. If the current increases, as in this figure, the resulting increase in $H$ induces circulating eddy currents $I_W$ which partially cancel the current flow in the center and reinforce it near the skin.

Question: Why would the induced currents be circles in a plane as shown? It looks like the induced magnetic field should produce currents $I_W$ directly opposing $I.$